# Multiple apps, single login?

Tags: symfony1, sfguard

My symfony project is divided into several apps. Using the sfDoctrineGuard plugin I'd like to create another app just for login, and redirect to the appropriate app after login.

- Is this advisable or does it go against how sfGuard is supposed to work?
- Is there a way to redirect between applications without hardcoding the entire url? Is there a "symfony way" of doing it, or is this not how projects are supposed to function?

(All I can find is [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/bb7174b5d619f0ed) which is kind of vague on the specifics.)

Comment: Well, **symfony** apps are actually designed to group controllers, not to separate (for example) login site and main one. Unless you're planning to implement some sort of SSO, you don't actually need to create separate app **only** for authentication-related things.

Comment: But if I have frontend and backend apps and they both require login, where should the login go? Either way, one will have to redirect to the other. I thought it would be simpler to have a separate login app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think it doesn't. Symfony uses the same session for both users (frontend and backend) so just use the same *sfBasicSecurityUser* class (the same *myUser* class)
- You probably need [Cross Application Links](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/2009/02/17/cross-application-links). I've already used this tutorial and it works perfectly!

Comment: I ended up rethinking my project architecture and it made more sense to combine my apps so as not to need multiple logins, but the cross application links look interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to the first part; but there is a cross-application link [plugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/swCrossLinkApplicationPlugin) that I have used.